# Internet Explorer freezes when a click + drag mouse action is performed. How to detect the cause of this?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, profiling, freeze

I am working on a JavaScript application for creating simple diagrams, and I have some performance issues in Internet Explorer (version 8).

The app can be used to draw lines on a diagram (See picture). There are two main handlers for drawing a line. An ONMOUSEUP event picks up user's clicks which indicate that the user wants to place a point on the line and start a new segment (lines consist of multiple segments).

An ONMOUSEMOVE handler draws a faded-out segment as a visual help to the user while he is drawing the line.

Please refer to these images for a screenshot of line-drawing process:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxcFr.jpg
http://i51.tinypic.com/fxjqf.jpg

If a user clicks the mouse (mousedown) but **doesnt** release it, and instead starts dragging the mouse around, IE completely freezes. After some time, it will unfreeze and proceed as usual.

Chrome on the other hand, handles this perfectly well (while the drag operation is happening, the MOUSEMOVE handler works its job, and the point is placed only after the ONMOUSEUP event fires.

My theory is that Explorer might be single-threaded in which case he picks up the MOUSEMOVE events but performs them only after the ONMOUSEUP event has completed (which means that esentially nothing is done for the duration of the drag operation), but I don't know how to check if this is true, or how to fix it.

I have done some profiling with the IE8 built-in JS profiler, and both handlers are called the usual amount of times, there are no functions being called thousands of times which would cause the freeze. The profiler is frozen while IE is frozen and outputs nothing until it unfreezes, after which the results seem the same as if there were no freeze action.

EDIT: Here is the timeline according to the dynaTrace profiler tool: http://i51.tinypic.com/348sxty.jpg.

Comment: Are you creating the diagrams and faded lines in normal html elements?

Comment: @Esailija yes, they are span elements mostly. Points have a background image, whereas the lines are transparent elements with a top or right border.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that updating the DOM is a very expensive operation. Now, the mousemove event fires constantly if not throttled and older browsers just can't keep up if you are updating the DOM on every mousemove event that is fired.

A solution **could** be throttling the mousemove event by at least 200 milliseconds. This means that you will only update the DOM after the mouse has stopped moving for 200 milliseconds, giving the browser some time to recover.

This is how you would throttle the mousemove event:

```
jQuery( "#element").bind( "mousemove", function(){
//Code to react to mousemove goes here
//Also add code here to check if the position has actually changed from last time,
//So you don't update the DOM for nothing
}.throttle( 200 ) );
```

Code required for the throttle method:

```
Function.prototype.throttle = function( delay ) {
var timeridto = 0, callback = this;

    function r(){
    var     args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ),
        self = this;
        clearTimeout( timeridto );
        timeridto = setTimeout( function(){callback.apply( self, args ); }, delay );
    };

    r.cancel = function(){
     clearTimeout( timeridto );   
    }

    return r;
};
```

If this doesn't solve the problem then you could use the html5 `canvas` or ([excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) for IE) for drawing operations.

Comment: I have already done some performance optimization here, by enforcing the lines to be drawn only on the grid (shown in the image). 

That way I only update the DOM when a mouse has moved at least 10px on the x or y axis.

When a user draws the line normally, there are no performance issues in IE. By normally i mean CLICK_MOUSE (a point is created), MOVE_MOUSE (a line is drawn from starting point in that direction), CLICK, MOVE, CLICK, MOVE.. etc. This use case works fine in every browser.

Comment: However, a MOUSEDOWN + MOUSEMOVE combination while drawing the line in IE completely freezes the browser.

So, to sum: MOUSEDOWN + MOUSEUP = CLICK -> MOUSEMOVE -> CLICK -> MOVE works fine.

MOUSEDOWN + MOUSEMOVE (click not completed) = freeze issues

Comment: Do you have any page where I can see it or can you put up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: No, I am sorry, my NDA prevents me from putting it up online.

Comment: I cannot really tell from your post what operations are taking place while dragging and what operations are taking place with mousemove without dragging. Is the helper faded out line only being drawn while dragging and is it also optimized?

Comment: Helper line segment is drawn from the last point placed on the diagram to the place where the mouse is now. The line segment is always vertical or horizontal. This redrawing is optimized so that it happens only when necessary (mouse has moved by at least 10px on x or y axis). The mousemove operation happens whenever the line tool is active. It doesnt matter if the user is dragging or clicking, the mousemove is called either way.

Comment: I am sorry, I really have no idea what could be causing this if same functions are called during mousemove regardless of the state of the mouse button :(

Comment: Here is a picture of the drawing process. If at step 3 you press a left mouse button and drag your mouse in any direction without releasing the mouse button, the IE will freeze. If you complete a click before moving the mouse, the application will work as intended (no performance issues).

http://i51.tinypic.com/fxjqf.jpg